# java spring jpa specification predicates array for search

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, specifications, predicates

I want to create a search in my java spring boot application ,and i'm using 
"Spring Data JPA" specification.I want to know how to use multiple predicates in "Spring Data jpa" specification.Here the example i [refer](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).

Answer (score 0):

You can only have 1 specification per find. If you want more, you have to link them with an `and` or `or` function, like:

`Predicate orPredicate = builder.or(predicate1, predicate2);`